# Change the size of the y axis in the matrix of. Complex Upset Plot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, upsetplot, complex-upset

How does now change the size of the labels (tick labels) of the y axis in the matrix section of an Upset plot made with Complex Upset in R? I tried using the `matrix=(intersection_matrix()+theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=200)))` and nothing happens

Changes using a similar approach for the `set_size()`  work. Hopefully this part of the plots is modifiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection matrix uses a default theme from a list of themes. The `ComplexUpset` documentation includes an example demonstrating how to change the font size in intersection matrix in [6.2 Adjusting the default themes](https://krassowski.github.io/complex-upset/articles/Examples_R.html#adjusting-the-default-themes) chapter. For you question it translates to:

```
upset(
    movies, genres, width_ratio=0.1,
    themes=upset_modify_themes(
        list('intersections_matrix'=theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=20)))
    )
)
```

I assume you either wanted to change `axis.text.y` or `axis.title.x` as there is no useful `axis.title.y`.

[image]